# How to copy/install assembly in a GAC? (Some problem running NUnit)

Tags: nunit, gac

I have NUnit installed at this directory.

```
C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0
```

I made the directory beneath a GAC.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\NUnit
```

and copied the nunit.framework.dll, but I got the same error.

When I try to run my unit test (mut.dll) in some random directory. I get the following error. I have to copy the mut.dll under the NUnit directory in order to run it.

```
ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-2.0
Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.5.10112, Culture=n
eutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The system
cannot find the file specified.
```

- What went wrong? How can I install/copy the assembly inside a GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the NUnit directory to your PATH environment variable, that might take care of it.

Otherwise, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176850/nunit-assembly-not-found) stack overflow post for other ideas.

Comment: @prosseek - I just came across this stackoverflow question, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176850/nunit-assembly-not-found